# Axios recursion for paginating an api with a cursor

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, axios

How can I paginate an API with a cursor using `axios`?  I would like to recursively call this function until `response.data.length < 1` and return the entire array with all items in the collection when it is done.  Also, worth noting, I would have to pass the cursor into subsequent calls.

```
function getUsers () {
    return axios.get('/users') // API supports a cursor param (?after=)
             .then(response => {
               // returns an array with a cursor
               // see response below
               console.log(response.data)
             })
}
```

Example response:

```
{
    "total": 100,
    "data": [
        {
            user: "Bob"
        },
        {
            user: "Sue"
        },
        {
            user: "Mary"
        },
    ],
    "pagination": {
        "cursor": "lkdjsfkljsdkljfklsdjfkjsdk"
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here's a recursive function that manages the cursor from the response:

```
function getUsers (cursor, data = []) {
    return axios.get('/users' + (cursor ? '?after='+cursor : '')) // API supports a cursor param (?after=)
      .then(response => {
          if (response.data.length < 1 ) return data
          data.push(...response.data)
          return getUsers(response.pagination.cursor, data)
      })
}
// use it to get data
getUsers()
.then(data => console.log("final data", data))
```

This is how it might work with a faked `axios` function and some extra logging to show the ordering:

```js
// Fake axios get -- just return numbers so it's easy to test
let axios = {
    data: data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
    get(url) {
        let cursor = parseInt(url.split('?after=')[1] || 0)
        console.log("cursor:", cursor)
        let ret_data = data.slice(cursor, cursor +5)
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve({
            "total": 15,
            "data": ret_data,
            "pagination": {
                "cursor": cursor +5
            }
            }), 400)
        )
    }
}

function getUsers (cursor, data = []) {
    return axios.get('/users' + (cursor ? '?after='+cursor : '')) // API supports a cursor param (?after=)
             .then(response => {
               console.log("getting data", response.data)
               if (response.data.length < 1 ) return data
               data.push(...response.data)
               return getUsers(response.pagination.cursor, data)
             })
}
getUsers()
.then(data => console.log("final data", data))
```

Comment: Thank you for this.  This seems to work with a few modifications, mostly around how `axios` works and the API's shape.

`data.push(...response.data.data)` 
`return getUsers(response.data.pagination.cursor, data)`

Comment: Cool @TechnoTim glad was at least pointing in the right direction.

Comment: @TechnoTim This modification is needed because if the API returns only one page, the function will return empty data. Thus, it must push to array before handling pagination. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Have a separate recursive function that takes an array, gets `/users`, and either pushes to the array and calls itself again, or resolves if there are no more users:

```
function getUsers () {
  getOne()
    .then((users) => {
      // got all users
    });
}

const getOne = (users = []) => axios.get('/users')
  .then(({ data }) => {
    // Resolve the promise initialized in `getUsers` with the final array:
    if (data.length < 1) return users;
    // Else, push to the array and chain another promise onto the end:
    users.push(...data);
    return getOne(users);
  })
```

Comment: Thank you for this.  I am going to accept Mark's answerbecause it included the logic for the cursor.  Thank you for the help!