# Get DRF paginated endpoint from axios

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework, axios, vuex

I have a paginated endpoint in my `django-rest-framework` API. A response to a list GET request looks like this:

```
{
"count": 161,
"next": "http://localhost:8000/api/v2/bars/?limit=50&offset=50",
"previous": null,
"results": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Bar1",
        "url": "http://localhost:8000/api/v2/bars/1/",
        "budget": 800000,
    },
    // more items...
]
}
```

What is the best approach if I want to fetch from `axios` all that pages until the end and then dump it to my `vuex` state?

My current code only gets the first page. The `axios` session request:

```
bars() { return session.get('/bars/') }
```

The `vuex` action:

```
barsRefresh(context) {
    api.bars().then((data) => context.commit('setBars', data.results))
}
```

Comment: check in response json if next is null or not if its not null then hit the next url otherwise stop

Comment: This is what I am trying to code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51511009/5940809) answer, I made a factory that takes a url and returns a working function:

```
// returns a promise once it gets ALL pages from API
function paginated_factory(url) {
    return function paginatedFetcher(next, obj_list = []) {
        return session.get(next ? next : url)
            .then(({data}) => {
                obj_list.push(...data.results)
                if (!data.next) return obj_list
                return paginatedFetcher(data.next, obj_list)
            })
    }
}
```

Then, my API module function:

```
bars: paginated_factory('/bars/')
```

And my vuex action:

```
barsRefresh(context) {
    api.bars().then((data) => context.commit('setBars', data))
},
```