# Recursion with an API, using Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, api, recursion

I'm playing with the Rick and Morty API and I want to get all of the universe's characters
into an array so I don't have to make more API calls to work the rest of my code.

The endpoint `https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/` returns the results in pages, so
I have to use recursion to get all the data in one API call.

I can get it to spit out results into HTML but I can't seem to get a complete array of JSON objects.

I'm using some ideas from
[Axios recursion for paginating an api with a cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51510699/axios-recursion-for-paginating-an-api-with-a-cursor)

I translated the concept for my problem, and I have it posted on my [Codepen](https://codepen.io/kingram/pen/PoNzRKd)
This is the code:

```
async function populatePeople(info, universePeople){ // Retrieve the data from the API
  let allPeople = []
  let check = ''
  try {
        return await axios.get(info)
            .then((res)=>{
                // here the current page results is in res.data.results
                for (let i=0; i < res.data.results.length; i++){
                    item.textContent = JSON.stringify(res.data.results[i])
                    allPeople.push(res.data.results[i])
                }

                if (res.data.info.next){
          check = res.data.info.next
                return allPeople.push(populatePeople(res.data.info.next, allPeople))
                }
            })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(`Error: ${error}`)
    } finally {
    return allPeople
    }
}

populatePeople(allCharacters)
  .then(data => console.log(`Final data length: ${data.length}`))
```

Some sharp eyes and brains would be helpful.
It's probably something really simple and I'm just missing it.

Comment: Please reformat your code so that its more readable. Also, please strip down the problem to its basic part. We are not here to write your code for you. I would suggest that you try to make it work wihout recursion. As soon as it works without recursion, you can refactor your code to use recursion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following line has problems:

```
return allPeople.push(populatePeople(res.data.info.next, allPeople))
```

Here you push a promise object into `allPeople`, and as `.push()` returns a number, you are returning a number, not `allPeople`.

Using a `for` loop to `push` individual items from one array to another is really a verbose way of copying an array. The loop is only needed for the HTML part.

Also, you are mixing `.then()` with `await`, which is making things complex. Just use `await` only. When using `await`, there is no need for recursion any more. Just replace the `if` with a loop:

```
while (info) {
   ....
   info = res.data.info.next;
}
```

You never assign anything to `universePeople`. You can drop this parameter.

Instead of the plain `for` loop, you can use the `for...of` syntax.

As from `res` you only use the `data` property, use a variable for that property only.

So taking all that together, you get this:

```
async function populatePeople(info) {
    let allPeople = [];
    try {
        while (info) {
            let {data} = await axios.get(info);
            for (let content of data.results) {
                const item = document.createElement('li');
                item.textContent = JSON.stringify(content);
                denizens.append(item);
            }
            allPeople.push(...data.results);
            info = data.info.next;
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(`Error: ${error}`)
    } finally {
        section.append(denizens);
        return allPeople;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that exhaustive and exceedingly polite code review.

Comment: Thanks, @trincot for showing us how to review code, I have to learn this level of explaining :)

Comment: My third read through of the refactor, I'm just boggled by how elegant that is. I feel like a complete idiot from how difficult I made that. I clearly need a lot more practice with my algorithm creation.

Comment: It's not idiotic at all. Sometimes you are already exhausted mentally when you ask questions and write code. So anyone who been in that situation understanding this situation. That's why there is StackOverflow. Sometimes people are so mean here unfortunately, but as you know more knowledge = being more humble.

Comment: True. Thanks for the time @ubeyt-demir. Definitely learning from the people who share of their time with graciousness. I will be pay it forward as I am able.

Comment: I have not seen this assignment before "let {data} = ...". How do we name it?

Comment: Ahhh.. I looked it up. Destruturing. Not covered in detail in this coding bootcamp. Not yet anyway. It's only week 3 of 12.

Comment: Without destructuring you can do `let data = (await axios.get(info)).data;`.

Comment: And if you did not cover the spread syntax yet (`...`), then you can do instead: `allPeople = allPeople.concat(data.results)`

Answer (score 3):

Here is working example for recursive function

```
async function getAllCharectersRecursively(URL,results){
    try{
        const {data} =  await axios.get(URL);
        //  concat current  page results
        results =results.concat(data.results)
        if(data.info.next){
            // if there is next page call recursively
            return await getAllCharectersRecursively(data.info.next,results)
        }
        else{
            // at last page there is no next page so return collected results
            return results
        }
    }
    catch(e){
        console.log(e)
    }
}

async function main(){
    let results = await getAllCharectersRecursively("https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/",[])
    console.log(results.length)
}
main()
```

Comment: That's  a great answer. @trincot provided a an explanation and a refactor with my own code so I'm going to accept his answer.

Answer (score 2):

I hesitate to offer another answer because Trincot's analysis and answer is spot-on.

But I think a recursive answer here can be quite elegant.  And as the question was tagged with "recursion", it seems worth presenting.

```js
const populatePeople = async (url) => {
  const {info: {next}, results} = await axios .get (url)
  return [...results, ...(next ? await populatePeople (next) : [])]
}

populatePeople ('https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/')
  // or wrap in an `async` main, or wait for global async...
  .then (people => console .log (people .map (p => p .name)))
  .catch (console .warn)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script>/* dummy */ const axios = {get: (url) => fetch (url) .then (r => r .json ())} </script>
```

This is only concerned with fetching the data.  Adding it to your DOM should be a separate step, and it shouldn't be difficult.

### Update: Explanation

A comment indicated that this is hard to parse.  There are two things that I imagine might be tricky here:

- First is the [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) in `{info: {next}, results} = <...>`.  This is just a nice way to avoid using intermediate variables to calculate the ones we actually want to use.
- The second is the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) in `return [...results, ...<more>]`.  This is a simpler way to build an array than using `.concat` or `.push`.  (There's a similar feature for objects.)

Here's another version doing the same thing, but with some intermediate variables and an array concatenation instead.  It does the same thing:

```js
const populatePeople = async (url) => {
  const response = await axios .get (url)
  const next = response .info && response .info .next
  const results = response .results || []
  const subsequents = next ? await populatePeople (next) : []
  return results .concat (subsequents)
}
```

I prefer the original version.  But perhaps you would find this one more clear.

Comment: wow. quite sharp. will take me some time to parse that.

Comment: @KenIngram: added an explanation.  Hope it helps.

Comment: It would take me a bit to parse because I don't have a great deal of projects under my belt, so most of the syntax is new and I'd have to look it up. Overall it seems powerful and brief.